# phpMyAdmin Designer with just 1 database. Alternatives?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I bought a 1and1.es (Spain) Starter hosting plan for a small project we are starting. It only allows one database. I never imagined that to enable phpMyAdmin Designer (the graphical tab where you set relations between tables) you'd need to create another database. Of course, when I try to, I get an "access denied" error.

So, assuming I can't use phpMyAdmin, I haven't been able to find the right term to look for an alternative MySQL manager that has some kind of graphical relation creator. I just converted the tables to InnoDB and I have Relation View, but a totally-unskilled team has to work with it so we need visuals.

PS: I just saw I can pay 1$/month and have another database, so I might consider it (it'w low price, but feels useless having a 1GB database just for a silly database. I don't get why phpMyAdmin needs another database just for that).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you imagine that the phpMyAdmin configuration storage needs a separate database?

According to http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage,
"you need to create a set of special tables. Those tables can be located in your own database,"...